# Xbox Live C# API Leaderboard Example

Tags: xbox-live

I signed up for the Xbox Creators Program, and I'm trying to get a leaderboard. However I couldn't find any examples that use the C# API. [This page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/data-platform/leaderboards/leaderboards) shows how to do it in C++.

Here is my code. It won't build because it says `XboxLiveContext doesn't have a LeaderboardService property`. How do I create a leaderboardservice in C#?

```
XboxLiveUser user = new XboxLiveUser();

SignInResult x = await user.SignInAsync();

XboxLiveContext context = new XboxLiveContext(user);

LeaderboardResult result = await context.LeaderboardService.GetLeaderboardAsync("scores1", new LeaderboardQuery());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C# Xbox Creators Program some of the APIs have been moved around.  The Leaderboards APIs are now part of the `StatsManager`.  You can use `StatsManager.Singleton.GetLeaderboard(...)` make a request to get a leaderboard.

That starts the request in the background, and when it's complete, an event will be returned by a call to `StatsManager.Singleton.DoWork()`.  The `DoWork` method is intended to be called every frame (or whenever you want to be notified of events from StatsManager).  Take a look at the [Xbox Live Unity Plugin Leaderboards implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin/blob/master/Assets/Xbox%20Live/Scripts/Leaderboard.cs) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This is helpful. Now I am having an issue with the StatsManager in general. The other API's work for me, XBoxUser, SocialManager etc... but StatsManager is crashing on StatsManager.Singleton.AddLocalUser(user). Could it be I didn't set up stats correctly? according to this link I have to first set up my stats. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/data-platform/player-stats/player-stats however I don't have this link in my Dashboard. I only have the Xbox Live link under services. How do I create my Stats, is this a limitation of Creators Program Users?

Comment: StatsManager should be working properly, however if you have separate questions can you mark this answer as final and submit a new question with any additional error detail you might be seeing?

Comment: @nbarkhina Did you get leaderboards working with C#. I've tried and it errors/throws and exception when just accessing the EventArgs that contains the leaderboards. Even though the ErrorCode is 0?!? If you have any  ideas, I'd love to pick your brain.

Comment: Yes I did get it to work. Though the leaderboard apis don't do much. I use them though the statistics don't seem to be accessible from anywhere, but if you're interested I can help you get it going.